# What was Allah doing before the creation

Tags: allah, creation

What was Allah doing before the creation? Is there a Hadith for this? Was God making other words before our own?

Answer (score 2):

Someone very beautifully answered this question [here](https://www.quora.com/What-was-Allah-doing-before-creation).

To summarize, Allah is above all constraints like space, time, energy and matter. These cannot be applied to Allah like it does to His creation. Allah was, is and will be. There is no beginning to Him nor an End. So to ask what Allah was doing before / now or after is illogical. If you are asking from the human perspective as to what Allah was doing before He created anything, then the knowledge of the unseen is only with Allah and very little has been given to us (little and good enough to be able to believe in Allah).

Humans have always been curious beings. Islam encourages to question and ponder, but instead of focusing on what Allah was doing, we need to care about what are we doing now in this life to achieve the hereafter. Once faith enters the heart, the clear and the unclear..we accept all of it as it is..as it was made known by Allah to us. The matters of the unseen..if you question too much..there is plenty of room to go astray..we from the outside looking in cannot understand a lot of things now (hell, heaven, angels, death, resurrection)..it is all part of the test. But Allah has given us simple examples to understand some concepts of the unseen so that we can relate to them. Death is like sleep, resurrection is like how the earth turns green after it was once dry, etc..We will see it all for real the moment we die and when later we are resurrected.

Answer (score 2):

I start with quoting a statement by [Musa ibn Jaffar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musa_al-Kadhim), a descendant of Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) who is considered a scholarly and spiritual authority by Shia Muslims, recorded in a famous theology hadith book, named [*at-Tawheed as-Saduq*](http://en.wikishia.net/view/Al-Tawhid_(book)):

> أنّه قال: إنّ الله تبارك و تعالي كان لم يزلْ بلا زمانٍ و لا مكان و هو
> الآنَ كما كان لا يَخلو منه مكانٌ و لا يَشغل به مكان و لا يحُلُّ في مكان
>
> He said: Allah has always been without time or place and He is in
> the same state now. No place is devoid of Him, and He
> occupies no place and in no place He resides. ([source](http://lib.eshia.ir/15046/1/179/%DB%8C%D8%B4%D8%BA%D9%84))

This account has several implications:

Allah is essentially beyond time and space.

Therefore, talk of "before" and "after" for Allah is absurd since these two adverbs presume Allah to be subject to time.

It also means God's relation to any point in time is the same as His relation to any other point in time. That is for Allah time doesn't pass. Everything since pre-eternity to eternity are known and present to Him all at once.

Time is indeed an illusion in a deeper sense. What there is is always present! Hence:

What is in store for "future" is already present and known to God. "There is not a thing but with us is its stores" -- Quran.

"Present" is about God presenting to us what has been eternally present to Him but absent to us.

"Past" means something eternally known to God has been just taken away from our sight! So nothing can be actually "lost in history" from an eternal point of view!

It also means, there is a logical possibility that are indefinite number of universes running parallels to ours with their own time and space all simultaneously known to God.

**So the question reduces to this: what is God doing in His state of transcendence from time and place?**

**Answer:** Nothing for that would be the station of His essence where there is no change, potential, motion, or expectation. **There He only is!**

But the traditions suggest that in His eternal state of individuality God desired to be known, hence He created the creation to be known.

Now because we ruled out the possibility of change and motion in God or affection by time, that means Allah *eternally* wants to be known, so He *eternally* creates things including time.

So there is no time without creation basically because time is always linked to creation. So we have to say that there is no creation without time but since God constantly creates there will always be time as a byproduct.

So God eternally is, hence He eternally creates. There is no before and after for Him in relation to His creation. Before and after are illusions that affect our limited conditioned existence.

Indeed traditions suggest that for superior beings like some angels time passes so quickly that we can say it's been perhaps like a few seconds since Adam was created depending on how superior the perceiving being is. But for God it would not be even a blinking of an eye! Not even an instant. For God everything only is, no becoming.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum

All praise to Allah

The answer is very simple , if you know the theory of big bang before big bang time didn't exist so your question was what was Allah doing before creating us you used the words before and was which is past tense and past tense is connected to time so before big bang time didn't exist

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum, may Allah (SWT) let my words from the righteous.

Brother, Allah (SWT) has created time, and space, so he's free from them. Rules are from him, not that he's from the rules. And, to clear out the confusions, after that the creation comes to an end, there's nothing left, Allah (SWT)'s is the only entity left. Allah created us from will to create us, just like we created simulations & games, though not comparing the almighty to us but just for the sake of explanation. Anyways, when there was nothing, the will was of nothing and then was the will to create, so were we created.

Wallahu-Alam.

Answer (score 0):

***What was Allah doing before the creation?***

By asking the very question you presume that there are a time span where there are no any matter and change of that matter.

How we know that time passes? By observing (and countining) repeatable events - changes in our world, like raising sun, moon, moving of a watch arrow.

When there is no matter, when there is no things - concept of time become meaningless.

***Was God making other words before our own?***

About the second question I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

Allah has many creations, trillions of worlds before this world, and will create many after this world. See Islam Hadith.

See this link: https://myenglishblog.persianblog.ir/x35w0Av9xmHlvB7Ynm8n-Is-there-another-creature-before-Adam-peace-be-upon-him-in-the-ground